# pm2 scheduled reloading for some apps

Tags: node.js, pm2

is there a way to tell pm2 to automatic reload specific some apps that are running ?
for example lets say i have process that run in cluster mode and i want pm2 to reload all the instances once a day in production (and not based on file change)

this some example of my current process in eco-system file

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "script": "./app/microServices/test/test.js",
    "node_args": (process.env.NODE_DEBUG) ? ['--inspect=5882'] : [],
     "exec_mode": "cluster"
    "watch": false,
    "error_file": "./logs/test.log",
    "out_file": "./logs/test.log",
    "log_date_format": logDateFormat
},
```

is there someway to do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cron_restart` property ([doc](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)).

For your case, you can set `cron_restart` value is `0 0 12 1/1 * ? *`, this mean your application will auto restart at 12:00 PM every day.

Your final eco-system file be like:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "script": "./app/microServices/test/test.js",
  "node_args": (process.env.NODE_DEBUG) ? ['--inspect=5882'] : [],
  "exec_mode": "cluster",
  "watch": false,
  "error_file": "./logs/test.log",
  "out_file": "./logs/test.log",
  "log_date_format": logDateFormat,
  "cron_restart": "0 0 12 1/1 * ? *"
}
```

Comment: thanks, i see it runs restart, is there such an option to "pm2 reload" option and not restart ?